# php7 popen in windows utf-8 chars issue

Tags: php, json, windows, firebase, utf-8

recently i migerated an old application from php5.6 to php7.4, made compatibility changes and everything works except a popen command that send notifications using firebase, the command is:

```php
pclose(popen("start c:\path-to\curl.exe --header \"Authorization: key=firebase-key\" --header \"Content-Type: application/json\" -d \"".addcslashes(json_encode($fields,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE),'\\"')."\" -X POST \"https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send\"","r"));
```

the notification is in persian and utf-8 encoding, it works great on same IIS server with php5.6 but when i use php7.4 the notification will be ?????? (question marks), any ideas what is the issue ?

**Update**
Tested with PHP7.2 on Widnows IIS and the issue exists.
Tested with PHP7.2 on Linux NGINX FPM and works fine.

Comment: Why do you use curl with popen and not the curl extension?

Comment: Where do things go wrong? I see multiple statements in your code, try to narrow it down. is `popen` not sending stuff correctly, can `CURL` not handle unicode it or is `addcslashes` acting out.

Comment: @Bernhard we may send 10000 messages all together with different message bodies for each user and firebase doesn't support such multiple format sending in its api, in such scenario the command approach is much much faster than using curl extension.

Comment: @Joeri , command works well and sends the notification but it is in malformed encoding and user see question marks instead, as i mentioned it works great in php5.6 and user receives the correct message and the issue is for php7.4.

Comment: What do you mean by "command", do you mean your call to `curl.exe`, your call to `cmd`, your call to `start` or your call to `popen`

Comment: @Joeri i mean the whole popen call from php works and notification receives by client, the issue here is not any error! the issue is the json_encode($fields,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) has utf-8 chars that by sending it using the above code transforms it to question marks! and it only happens for php7 on IIS.

Comment: I'm not talking about an error, I mean where are they transformed into question marks. You are making several calls and somewhere along the way stuff is going wrong. What function converts the Unicode characters into question marks

Comment: @Joeri i think it is popen call that transforms the unicode text into question marks.